# Derailleur play between cage and knuckle

Tags: shimano, derailleur

I have a Shimano 2300 rear mech that's done about 10,000m over ~7 years. Lately I've had trouble getting clean shifting and find myself constantly twiddling barrel adjusters... I'm certain the cable tension is good and (by my eye) the mech hanger is straight, but there's a certain amount of play between the cage and the body:

[image]

Will this affect the shifting much and, if so, is it repairable, or time to get a new mech?

**EDIT**
Closer shot of the hanger, which does look like it has a slight bend in it, now that I can zoom in this close without my long-sightedness furring things over somewhat.
[image]

Comment: '2300/Claris' and 7years+, sure there will be some play. About time for a change. It won't be that expensive.

Comment: That amount of play is not unusual.  However, it looks like the derailer or hanger may be slightly bent.  (Can't tell for sure from this distance.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks - I'm not so sure myself, on the hangar now. Does the edit make it clearer?

Comment: I'll note that the bolt used to secure derailers to hangers is often the same size and thread as some common axles.  I have, in our shop, grabbed an axle out of the used parts bin, threaded it (with a nut installed) into the hanger, tightened the nut against the hanger, and then used a length of pipe to "encourage" the thing to move in the right direction.  An advantage of this approach over simply using a wrench on the hanger is that the axle is good indicator of the alignment of the  hanger.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Judging by the added pic: the hanger is slightly inwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How worn are the cassette and chains? How old is the shifter cable.

In my experience the order of things that cause shifting issues are chain wear, cassette wear, cables first. In my mind these are all considered consumables and replaced regularly. Derailleur hanger, especially if unknown history, is a likely suspect

Last is derailleur itself.  At 10000km on a Claris it past its 'economic life', so I would not be worried about replacing it.  The play in the video is a bit more than I would like, but I hesitate to say it is definitely the cause of your shifting issues.

Comment: Chain, Cassette and Crankset all replaced within the last year. (I left it a bit late and it was jumping all over the place...). Cable is newer, but has been in long enough to have settled in. I'll add a clearer shot of the hangar. I thought it was straight, but now I'm not so sure...

Comment: Really you need the hanger tools to check straightness. You (Should I say I here?) cannot eyeball a hanger and say if it is definitely straight. If you have access to a tools, do that, otherwise a new derailleur is easy and at $20 possibly no more expensive than getting a shop to check the hanger.

Comment: Second look at the pic, I think @Danial is right - the hanger is does look bent to me.

Comment: Got a new mech coming from my LBS and a friend is lending me a hanger tool. I'm sure this will do the job, but will report back...